# Why this chisel code compiling without error with wrong size UInt assignement?

Tags: hdl, chisel

I declared a Module port like this (it was a mistake) in my top `RawModule`:

```scala
class TopMyModule extends RawModule {
...
  val enet1_tx_data0 = IO(Output(Bool()))
  val enet1_tx_data1 = IO(Output(Bool()))
...
  val tx1data = IO(Output(Bool()))
...
```

And connected it like this :

```scala
  tx1data := enet1_tx_data1 ## enet1_tx_data0
```

The '##' operator should concatenate the two bits in a vector of size to no ?
But it's compiling without any error.
If I'm looking under the verilog generated code, I see that concatenation is done but only least significant bit is used for output:

```
...
  wire [1:0] _T_1; // @[spiDualkszRmiiChecker.scala 73:29]
...
  assign _T_1 = {enet1_tx_data1,enet1_tx_data0}; // @[spiDualkszRmiiChecker.scala 73:29]
...
  assign tx1data = _T_1[0]; // @[spiDualkszRmiiChecker.scala 73:11]
```

In my mind `tx1data` should have been declared as 2 bits `UInt` :

```scala
  val tx1data = IO(Output(UInt(2.W)))
```

But I was surprised that first version doesn't generate any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an original design decision that some like and some do not. There is a good discussion on this issue [Remove implicit width truncation / Don't repeat Verilog's assignment issue in Chisel #1163](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/1163). Please feel free to chime in.